# Getting bad response trying to send a request

Tags: java, android, node.js, okhttp

I'm trying to send a request to a `NodeJS` server, I'm always getting `Bad Request` message with status code 400.
I tried using Postman to check if the problem was on the server, but in Postman it worked correctly.

I'm using OkHttp and trying to send a request like this:

```
private Request request;
private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
private void makePost(String nameOfProduct, String serialOfProduct, String priceOfProduct, String gender, String uriList, String colors, String sizes) {
    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("name", nameOfProduct)
            .addFormDataPart("serial",serialOfProduct)
            .addFormDataPart("price",priceOfProduct)
            .addFormDataPart("gender",gender)
            .addFormDataPart("color", colors)
            .addFormDataPart("size", sizes)
            .addFormDataPart("imagesUri",uriList)
            .build();
    Log.d("COLROS", colors);

    request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://10.0.2.2:4000/products/add")
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .post(requestBody)
            .build();

    try{
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
        }

        Headers responeHeaders = response.headers();
        for (int i = 0; i < responeHeaders.size(); i++) {
            Log.d("iu", "makePost: "+responeHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responeHeaders.value(i));
        }
        Log.d("iu", "makePost: "+response.body().string());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you sending form data and setting the ContentType header to application/json ?

Comment: Form data is not in JSON format

Comment: I followed the tutorial, I actually want to create a json object with the information I have, and send it in the request body.

Comment: If you want to send JSON, you should not be using `MultipartBody.FORM` to begin with

Comment: what should I use then? I tried many ways to send the JSON

Answer (score 0):

You are sending Form data (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) but setting the header as json

Try to remove the line:

```java
.header("Content-Type", "application/json")
```

and use:

```java
.header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

Comment: still does a "Bad request", im just trying to send a json in the post body.

Comment: If you want to send JSON,  just dont use `MultipartBody.FORM` and `.addFormDataPart("name", nameOfProduct)`. Instead, build JSON from your object using GSON: https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: how do I send it after I built it ? with what `MultipartBody`?

Answer (score 0):

To send JSON data, you must build a JSON string. I'll use Gson library here, make sure you include it in your module level gradle file as follows:

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```

Next you need a class to serialize into JSON:

```java
public class Order {
    public String name;
    public String serial;
    public int price;
    public String gender;
    //Other fields go here...

    //This empty constructor is required by Gson
    public Order() {}
}
```

Now you build an object of this class as you require:

```java
private void makePost(String nameOfProduct, String serialOfProduct, String priceOfProduct, String gender, String uriList, String colors, String sizes) {
    Order order = new Order();
    order.name = nameOfTheProduct;
    order.price = priceOfTheProduct;
    //Fill in other fields here...

    //Now get a JSON data string from this object using Gson:
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonData = gson.toJson(order);

    public static final MediaType mediaTypeJSON = MediaType.get("application/json; charset=utf-8");

    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(mediaTypeJSON, jsonData);


    //Build the request
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("http://10.0.2.2:4000/products/add")
        .post(requestBody)
        .build();

    //Finally send the request as you already do in your code
    //Using the call: Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
}
```

Comment: If you still face a problem, share your back-end node.js code so I can know what exactly it is accepting.

Comment: which 'MediaType' should I import? because I dont have `MediaType.get()`. I only have `MediaType.parse()`

Comment: I am sure `MediaType.get()` exists, but you can use parse too, it's just slightly different: https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/MediaType.html#get-java.lang.String-

Comment: I'll try, I can't see it in the option, and when I try to type it `get()` I get compile error, will try with `parse()`

Comment: What version of OkHttp are you using ?

Comment: I still get `Bad Request`, using okHttp:  'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216368/discussion-between-qunata-and-pythwan).